# Is there existing ActionScript 1 or 2 code to encode BitmapData as GIF/JPG/PNG?

Tags: flash, image, actionscript

I have a BitmapData object that I'd like to encode as either GIF, JPG or PNG as a string in memory.  I've seen code to do this using ByteArray in AS3.  Is there any existing code to do this in AS1/2?

Edit: to clarify, I know that I can send the raw bitmap data to a server to do the encoding, but that is a last resort.  With this question, I'm looking for a method of doing this entirely in Flash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exhaustive search, it looks like the answer to my question is no; there is no such code available.  For anyone who comes across this question, it will be overwhelmingly easier to port your code to AS3, where you can make use of existing ByteArray-based image encoders, than to implement something in AS1/AS2.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is, but it is very slow:

http://www.flash-db.com/Tutorials/snapshot/index.php